# How can I check for equivalent in javascript object keys

Tags: javascript

I have this object, I want to make such users don't add other items to database , when there is an item in object with the same key name.

```
{
"0360841d73bd74b268dcc3abad2555c0": {
"file_dislikes": 0,
"file_likes": 0,
"slang": "mmmmmmmmm",
"slangDefine": "dddddddddd",
"slangExample": "ddddddd",
"slangID": "0360841d73bd74b268dcc3abad2555c0",
"time_date": "2016-09-15T16:28:19.384Z",
"user_id": "0Uwx4oXQVEckArRSZNerwhfDZFF3"
},
"072794611d87924ac134bc87ae202c05": {
"file_dislikes": 0,
"file_likes": 0,
"slang": "damnit",
"slangDefine": "Damnit",
"slangExample": "Damnit",
"slangID": "072794611d87924ac134bc87ae202c05",
"time_date": "2016-09-14T13:40:47.745Z",
"user_id": "bHDKSU6aorX9efzBCHyVI4JBTh53"
}
}
```

I have the items in the object vm.slangs

```
 for (var keys in vm.slangs) {
     var getThisObject = vm.slangs[keys];
     if ((getThisObject.slang).toLowerCase() === ("Damnit").toLowerCase()) {
           console.log("there is a slang with that name!");
           // Item cannot be added to database.
       }
    }
```

I thought this should work , but it doesn't maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Assuming `vm.slangs` points to the object structure you've shown, it *does* work. https://jsfiddle.net/jkjhtdbv/

Comment: Though you say *"... when there is an item in object with the same key name"*, when in fact you're testing the *value*, not the key name. That's probably what you meant. And you haven't told us what *"doesn't work"* means.

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in your debugger?

Comment: @Ericel yes what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a flag and exit the loop, if the slang is found and prevent an insert into the db.

```
var unique = true;

for (var keys in vm.slangs) {
    var getThisObject = vm.slangs[keys];
    if (getThisObject.slang.toLowerCase() === "Damnit".toLowerCase()) {
        console.log("there is a slang with that name!");
        unique = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (unique) {
    // add to db
}
```

Comment: This may well be what the OP wants to do, but why doesn't his original code work?